# How to apply css using a condition?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply this css:

```
#calendar-page #calendar .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
}
```

this works well, the problem is that the web app can set a class on the `body` called `white-content`, if the `white-content` class is setted, then I can't see the text of `h2`, because the color is `white`.

Is possible tell to css that the css above must be applied only when the `white-content` class is not availble on `body`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use not() selector

Comment: `.white-content #calendar-page #calendar .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar h2 {color: black;}`

Comment: @sol the h2 is already black.. I need to set white, I tried: `#calendar-page #calendar .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar h2:not(.white-content)` but no luck

Comment: @sfarzoso You can use both rules. The code you posted sets it white. The code in my comment sets it black when `white-content` is on the body.

Comment: @sfarzoso TemaniAfif means to use `body:not(.white-content) #calendar-page #calendar .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar h2` for a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've condensed the HTML for the sake of this example.

**Test 1:** Class *does* exist on `body`. `h2` text should be default black.

```css
body:not(.white-content) #calendar-page h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body class="white-content">
  <div id="calendar-page">
    <h2>My Header</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Test 2:** Class does *not* exist on `body`. `h2` text should be white.

```css
body:not(.white-content) #calendar-page h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="calendar-page">
    <h2>My Header</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
body.white-content
```

that means "body and white-content" class at the same time.
So you can use:

```
#calendar-page #calendar .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar h2 {
   font-size: 22px;
   color: white;
}
body.white-content #calendar-page #calendar .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar h2 {
   color: black
}
```

So when body has .white-content it add that css rule.

See more on
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score -3):

yes it's possible by using DOM manipulation with javascript:

html:

```
<div id="div01" style="background-color: white">abc</div>
```

javascript:

```
if(div01.style.backgroundColor == "white")
    {document.getElementById("div01").style.color = "black";}
```